# How to append text to form tag content

Tags: jquery

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<textarea>
<form class="formClass">
   <input id="foo" type="text">
</form>
</textarea>
```

Now I want to append some text to the form tag content, right after the input, in new line. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
$(".formClass").val("appended");
$(".formClass").val($(".formClass").val() + "appended");
$(".formClass").html("appended");
$(".formClass").text("appended");
```

And none works. Actually, without the argument, all functions return undefined when I try to get form content.

However, appending this (using the second method) to the textarea works fine. But I want to append it to the form tag.

Comment: why is a form nested in a textarea?

Comment: Im dynamically creating form html so that user can copy the code from textarea content.

Comment: Form cannot be nested inside a `<textarea>`!

You can't use `.val()` for `form`!

Comment: So how else could I do this?

Comment: are u writing the jquery in $(document).ready(function() ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:

```
var $textarea = $('textarea');
$textarea.val($($textarea.val()).append('appended').html());
```

See **[the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mm1oc2h8/1/)**.

The point is to use the content (via .val()) of the textarea to construct a jQuery object then append other text, then assign the html back to the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're selecting the wrong element

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textArea">
<form class="formClass">
   <input id="foo" type="text">
</form>
</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$("textArea").val($("textArea").val() + "appended")
```

Try this

Comment: The op want append to the form, not after the form. `right after the input `.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Right now the form is no html Element, it is simple plain text within a textarea.

You could build up your form first,  add your text and then put it with the val() function into the textarea. I used a span for demonstration.

Fiddle for my explanation:
https://jsfiddle.net/z7wtzuz9/

```
<textarea></textarea>
<form class="formClass">
    <input id="foo" type="text" />
</form>

$("<span>").insertAfter($(".formClass input"));
$("textarea").val($("form").prop('outerHTML'));
```

Don't forget to clean up the form afterwards ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't update it before inserted dynamically created element?
It's tricky, but should work.

```
$('textarea').val( $('textarea').val().replace('</form>', 'text foo </form>'));
```

or

```
var textarea=$('textarea'), 
    form=$(textarea.val()).append('some text');
textarea.val(form[0].outerHTML);
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/cqze6fw5/